# How to make cell delete itself based upon json value firebase realtime database

Tags: json, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I am retrieving data from firebase realtime database and I am pulling it all, and I need every cell to show the parent club only if its child "Promoted" has a value of "Yes" and if it does not I need the cell to delete itself and only 3 clubs ever have promoted being equal to "Yes"

it pulls it all, and displayed it all on the screen, but I am stuck on how to delete the cells where the children do not have promoted being equal to "Yes"

```
//tempViewController.swift
import Foundation
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class tempViewController: UIViewController ,  UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tempTableView: UITableView!
    var finalBar = [NightClubs]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tempTableView.dataSource = self
        tempTableView.delegate = self

        DataService.ds.REF_BARS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot.value as Any)
            if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                for snap in snapshot {
                    print(snap)
                    if let barData = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        let bar = NightClubs(barData: barData)
                        self.finalBar.append(bar)
                        print(self.finalBar)
                        self.tempTableView.reloadData()
                    }
                    self.tempTableView.reloadData()
                }
                self.tempTableView.reloadData()
            }
            self.tempTableView.reloadData()
        })
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView( _ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return  finalBar.count
    }

    func tableView( _ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tempTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newCell") as! newCell
        let barz = finalBar[indexPath.row]

        if barz.promoted == "Yes" {
            cell.setData(data: barz)
            // this sends the nightclubs that have .promoted == "Yes"
        } else {
            // need to remove the cell from the user view
            // as only 3 NightClubs will have promoted == "Yes"
            // so i only want to see 3 cells
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

```
//newCell.swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

class newCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationTextLabel: UILabel!



    func setData(data: NightClubs) {
        nameTextLabel.text = data.name
        locationTextLabel.text = data.location
    }


}
```

```
//NightClubs.swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

class NightClubs {

    private var _name: String!
    private var _location: String!
    private var _address: String!
    private var _latitude: String!
    private var _longitude: String!
    private var _promoted: String!
    private var _type: String!
    private var _liveCount: String!
    private var _goingCount: String!
    private var _description: String!

    var name: String! {
        return _name
    }

    var location: String! {
        return _location
    }

    var address: String! {
        return _address
    }

    var latitude: String! {
        return _latitude
    }

    var longitude: String! {
        return _longitude
    }

    var promoted: String! {
        return _promoted
    }

    var type: String! {
        return _type
    }

    var liveCount: String! {
        return _liveCount
    }

    var goingCount: String! {
        return _goingCount
    }

    var description: String! {
        return _description
    }

    init(name: String, location: String, address: String, latitude: String, longitude: String, promoted: String, type: String, liveCount: String, goingCount: String, description: String) {
        self._name = name
        self._location = location
        self._address = address
        self._latitude = latitude
        self._longitude = longitude
        self._promoted = promoted
        self._type = type
        self._liveCount = liveCount
        self._goingCount = goingCount
        self._description = description
    }

    init(barData: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
        if let name = barData["Name"] as? String {
            self._name = name
        }
        if let location = barData["Location"] as? String {
            self._location = location
        }
        if let address = barData["Address"] as? String {
            self._address = address
        }
        if let latitude = barData["Latitude"] as? String {
            self._latitude = latitude
        }
        if let longitude = barData["Longitude"] as? String {
            self._longitude = longitude
        }
        if let promoted = barData["Promoted"] as? String {
            self._promoted = promoted
        }
        if let type = barData["Type"] as? String {
            self._type = type
        }
        if let liveCount = barData["LiveCount"] as? String {
            self._liveCount = liveCount
        }
        if let goingCount = barData["GoingCount"] as? String {
            self._goingCount = goingCount
        }
        if let description = barData["Description"] as? String {
            self._description = description
        }
    }
}
```

I expected it to basically just show 3 children where its children equals "Yes" and there is no error as I am not doing anything at all to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do 1 of the following:

1) Either add the only bars in the finalBar array which has the promoted value as "Yes". For this update your data fetching code should be like.

```
DataService.ds.REF_BARS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot.value as Any)
    if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
        for snap in snapshot {
            print(snap)
            if let barData = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> 
            {
               let bar = NightClubs(barData: barData)
               // Add this check here
               if bar.promoted == "Yes" {
                   self.finalBar.append(bar)
               }
               print(self.finalBar)
            }
        }
    }
    self.tempTableView.reloadData()
 })
```

2) Or Create an other array and filter the finalBar array so it gives the only the bars with promoted as "Yes" and store it in different array. Then use this new array in showing up your cells.

e.g. `filteredFinalBars = finalBar.filter { $0.promoted == "Yes"}`

```
 DataService.ds.REF_BARS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot.value as Any)
    if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshot {
                print(snap)
                if let barData = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> 
                {
                   let bar = NightClubs(barData: barData)
                   self.finalBar.append(bar)
                   print(self.finalBar)
                }
            }
            //Add this to filter the bars with promoted as "yes".
            //Then use this array in tableView delegate and datasource methods
            filteredFinalBars = finalBar.filter { $0.promoted == "Yes"}
        }
        self.tempTableView.reloadData()
     })
```